# What's the default NTP server used by systemd-timesyncd?

Tags: linux, ntp, systemd-timesyncd

In my Linux distribution is enabled the service `systemd-timesyncd`. Very useful to understand how the service works is [this post answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/948974/force-systemd-timesyncd-to-sync-time-with-ntp-server-immediately/972336#972336).

Below I report some system information about this service:

- its unit file is: `/lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service`
- its configuration file is `/etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf`

I didn't change the default file `timesyncd.conf` and its content is showed below:

```
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#
# Entries in this file show the compile time defaults.
# You can change settings by editing this file.
# Defaults can be restored by simply deleting this file.
#
# See timesyncd.conf(5) for details.

[Time]
#NTP=
#FallbackNTP=time1.google.com time2.google.com time3.google.com time4.google.com
#RootDistanceMaxSec=5
#PollIntervalMinSec=32
#PollIntervalMaxSec=2048
```

In the file `timesyncd.conf` the option `NTP` is not set:

```
#NTP=
```

Nevertheless the service is able to set the system date and, by some logs in `journalctl`, I have seen that the reachable NTP server could be `time1.google.com`.

Where is set the NTP server (probably `time1.google.com`) used by `systemd-timesyncd`?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the timesyncd.conf man page.

```
CONFIGURATION DIRECTORIES AND PRECEDENCE
   The default configuration is defined during compilation, so a configuration file
   is only needed when it is necessary to deviate from those defaults. By default,
   the configuration file in /etc/systemd/ contains commented out entries showing the
   defaults as a guide to the administrator. This file can be edited to create local
   overrides.
```

Comment: Also relevant: `Any per-interface NTP servers obtained from systemd-networkd.service(8) take precedence over this setting, as do any servers set via NTP= above.` So, these servers are used when no NTP server is provided via networkd.

Comment: Thanks @Chris Woelkers I didn't read the [timesyncd manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/timesyncd.conf.5.html).

Comment: Thanks to @Gerald Schneider for the other info about networkd. I have read the [networkd manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/networkd.conf.5.html) but I don't find reference to NTP. I think that I have to study something about `systemd-networkd.service`.