# What's the policy synchronization with the NTP Server of the service systemd-timesyncd?

Tags: systemd-timesyncd

In my Linux distribution is enabled the service `systemd-timesyncd.service`.

Below it is shown the `/etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf` file (see [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/948974/force-systemd-timesyncd-to-sync-time-with-ntp-server-immediately/972336#972336) for find the following command):

```
[Time]
#NTP=
#FallbackNTP=time1.google.com time2.google.com time3.google.com time4.google.com
#RootDistanceMaxSec=5
PollIntervalMinSec=32
#PollIntervalMaxSec=2048
```

and below I show the commands sequence ***that I need to understand***:

```
####### stop synchronization with NTP server
$ timedatectl set-ntp false

####### Set tha datetime in the past
$ timedatectl set-time "2022-09-29 00:00:00"

####### restart synchronization with NTP server
$ timedatectl set-ntp true

###### immediately execution of the following command
$ date
```

The last command `date` (immediately executed after command `timedatectl set-ntp true`) gives the date and time already synchronized with the NTP Server.

**Instead I had assumed that with the setting `PollIntervalMinSec = 32` (see `timesyncd.conf` file) the NTP server is contacted after at least 32 seconds, but obviously this is not true.**

Someone can help me to find the parameter of the `/etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf` file that can set the delay before to connect the NTP server?

Thank you

Comment: You may be confusing the normal polling interval with a change that causes an immediate synchronization. With no changes, it polls on the regular interval, but any change causes an immediate synchronization.

Comment: Thanks @RonMaupin. I thought the same thing too but I was not sure. With the service `systemd-timesyncd` active if I change the date, immediately the NTP server is contacted and the date time are synchronized. The change of date is a trigger for the service.